# Declaring a variable without initializing it flutter

Tags: flutter, variables, static, declaration, non-nullable

I want to declare a static variable and initialize it in the following function, but get the error: "The non-nullable variable 'screenWidth' must be initialized."

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double defaultSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use either `late` keyword or use `?` after declaring the datatype of the variable so that flutter knows that you are gonna later initialise the variable at some point of time or the variable will be null .

Example:

`late int variable; //the variable will be initialised later`

OR

`int? variable; // the variable can either have a value or can be null.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `late` keyword as you are in null safety and you want to initialize the fields latter on.

By declaring a non-nullable late variable, we promise that it will be non-null at runtime, and Dart helps us with some compile-time guarantees.

But I recommend to only use late sparingly, and to always initialize late variables when they are declared.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static late MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static late double screenWidth;
  static late double screenHeight;
  static late double defaultSize;
  static late Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}
```

And here another thing is if you want to make your fields `nullable` then you cam make theme `nullable` by using `?` after the type like bellow.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData? _mediaQueryData;
  static double? screenWidth;
  static double? screenHeight;
  static double? defaultSize;
  static Orientation? orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData?.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData?.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData?.orientation;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add "late" keyword to your variables